# Does $f(s)\not= 0 \Rightarrow g(s)=0$ imply that $g(s)=0\Rightarrow f(s)\not= 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logic, proof-writing

I have the following implication:
$$f(s)\not= 0\Rightarrow g(s)=0$$
Then we can deduce that its converse is also true.
$$g(s)\not= 0\Rightarrow f(s)=0$$
where $f:\mathbb{C}→\mathbb{R},\,\,g:\mathbb{C}→\mathbb{C}$ and $g$ is analytic, but $f$ is not.

My question is as follows: can I deduce that $$g(s)=0⇒f(s)≠0\,\,\,?$$

Comment: What is the relation between $f$ and $g$? Are they connected is some ways?

Comment: I have $g(s)=ϕ(s)g(2-s)$ and $f=arg(ϕ(s))$ the complex argument of $ϕ(s)$.

Comment: That is a contrapostive not converse (difference, contrapostive is logically equivalent to the intial statement; knowing this saves you work.)

Comment: What does analytic mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  What if both functions are the zero function?

Also, you mean "contrapositive" and not "converse" in your second line.

Answer (score 5):

No! Put $P$ for $f(s) = 0$, $Q$ for $g(s) = 0$.

Then you are given $\neg P \Rightarrow Q$.

As you say, you can contrapose to get $\neg Q \Rightarrow P$.

But it would be a fallacy to infer $Q \Rightarrow \neg P$.

You can't normally reverse conditionals, after all! You can have $A \Rightarrow B$ true while the transposed $B \Rightarrow A$ is false.